# What I'm missing in $p=3^{q}\cdot 2^{r}$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, elementary-number-theory, prime-factorization, integers

> Given positive integer $p,q,r$ with $p=3^{q}\cdot 2^{r}$ and $100<p<1000$. The difference between maximum and minimum values of $(q+r)$ is?

My tries

It's clear that $p=6k$ for some positive integer $k$

Hence, $6*17=102\neq 3^{q}\cdot 2^{r}$, on trying next one $6*18=108=3^3\cdot2^2$
.Hence min $(q+r)=5$

Similarly, $972=6*162=3^52^2$, max $(q+r)=7$

difference $=2$, but didn't matched with answer given.

please help.

Comment: What about $p=512$?

Comment: $512=2^9\times3^0$; don't you like zero? If you don't like zero, how about $p=768$?

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown WE CAN'T USE $0$

Comment: $0$ isn't a *positive* integer.

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown ok $p=768$ works well, but how did you arrived at $768$?

Comment: While $512$ isn't relevant, $768 = 2^8\cdot 3$ is.

Comment: @mathlover if you calculate $\log_2 100$ and $\log_2 1000$ you have the range that $q$ can lie in; similarly if you calculate $\log_3 100$ and $\log_3 1000$ you have the range that $r$ can lie in.  You should get $1\leq q \leq 9$ and $1 \leq r \leq 8$ -- these are small enough ranges to brute-force

Comment: There are only $11$ possible values for the pair $(q,r)$.... If $q=1$ then $34\leq 2^r\leq 333$ so if $q=1$ then $6\leq r\leq 8$... If $q=2$ then $12\leq 2^r\leq 111$ so.... etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're finding the largest number of the form $2^p 3^q$, but that doesn't maximize $p+q$. As $2<3$ getting at high exponent on $2$ makes a smaller number than getting a high exponent of $3$. Trying the powers of $2$, we quickly find that $256=2^8$ is the highest that we can multiply by three and stay below $1000$.

Similar considerations might be relevant to find $\min(p+q)$.

And note that I haven't in any way proved that you'll find the $\min/\max$ this way, that's left for you.

Answer (score -1):

Yoou don'h have to take minimum and maximum values of $p$, but of $q+r$, which is the number of prime factors in the expanded notation. To minimize  $q+r$, we need larger factors appearing more. hence we search for numbers where $r=1$. For $162=2\cdot3^4$. Similarly, for maximum, $768=3\cdot2^8$. this gives difference 4